# Generate nested JSON from stored procedure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have sample data in a SQL Server table in the following format

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tempA
(
    HomeId int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    City nvarchar(20),
    State nchar(2),
    Email VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #tempA (City, State, Email) 
VALUES ('Cleveland', 'OH', 'sd@aol.com')

INSERT INTO #tempA (City, State, Email) 
VALUES ('Malibu', 'CA', 'sd@aol.com')

INSERT INTO #tempA (City, State, Email) 
VALUES ('Atlanta', 'GA', 'ploll@aol.com')
    
SELECT * FROM #tempA
```

I need a JSON output returned by a stored procedure in the following format, I am trying to group it by email field, I tried using JSON AUTO but not able to achieve in the following format ? Any tips?

```json
[
  {
    "Email": "sd@aol.com",
    "Tasks": [
          {
        "City": "Cleveland",
        "State": "OH"
      },
      {
        "City": "Malibu",
        "State": "CA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Email": "ploll@aol.com",
    "Tasks": [
      {
        "City": "Atlanta",
        "State": "GA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: *"I tried using JSON AUTO"* include your attempt in your question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use a subquery for the State and Email values and group on the email column in the outer query:

```sql
SELECT A.Email,
       (SELECT B.City,
               B.State
        FROM #tempA B
        WHERE A.Email = B.Email
        ORDER BY B.City ASC
        FOR JSON AUTO) AS Tasks
FROM #tempA A
GROUP BY A.Email
ORDER BY A.Email DESC
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Which gives:

```json
[
    {
        "Email": "sd@aol.com",
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "City": "Cleveland",
                "State": "OH"
            },
            {
                "City": "Malibu",
                "State": "CA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Email": "ploll@aol.com",
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "City": "Atlanta",
                "State": "GA"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```